# what i need to do for loading static

Tags: django

Hey everybody i have a problem with this code which i try to run on local host server , in this situation im followin an online project over youtube and he is trying to make an online resume, at the start we tried to make a simple home template which i stock in it so if u can help me to fix the problem in which cause to rise this error

> 'Static' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
>    admin_list
>    admin_modify
>    admin_urls
>    cache
>    i18n
>    l10n
>    log
>    static
>    tz

and this the code itself:

```
{% load  Static %}
<link href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css">

<h3> Hello world! <h3>

<img src="{% static 'images/me.profile.jpg'%}"
```

this is the setting.py by the way:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/Images/'


STATIC_DIRS= [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 
]
```

Comment: It's `static` not `Static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag is {% load static %} without the capital S.

Answer (score 0):

it's a recommended way or templating engine rules first make folder template or static folder then in template  make a new folder app_name.
then in app_name  work on static files.
in your app make a folder name `static` in it you make another folder name of your `app_name` init you work on your static files
e.g
static/app_name/images/me.profile.jpg
maybe problem also in this name `me.profile.jpg` please change it to 
profile.jpg.
you don't need to change anything in setting.py because static root default set .

```
{% load  static %}
<link href="{% static 'app_name/css/main.css' %}" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css">

<h3> Hello world! <h3>

<img src="{% static 'app_name/images/me.profile.jpg'%}" >
```